# run time error 3343 unrecognized database format

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Sub Export1line()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    
    Set db = OpenDatabase("FilePath")
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("TargetTableName", dbOpenTable)

    rs.AddNew
    rs.Fields("Column1") = Worksheets("To Export").Range("A2").Value
    rs.Fields("Column2") = Worksheets("To Export").Range("B2").Value
    rs.Fields("Column3") = Worksheets("To Export").Range("C2").Value
    rs.Fields("Column4") = Worksheets("To Export").Range("D2").Value
    rs.Fields("Column5") = Worksheets("To Export").Range("E2").Value
    rs.Fields("Column6") = Worksheets("To Export").Range("F2").Value
    
    rs.Update

    rs.Close
    db.Close

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I am trying to have a excel write to an access database and no matter what file path I select I get a 3343 error saying that path is in a unrecognized format.

I have tried changing the target database to .mdb files but I still get the same error.

Comment: Is the path local drive or remote eg. on OneDrive ?

Comment: Ive tried both local and onedrive saves and got the same error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using ADODB.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Export1line()

    Const DB = "FilePath"
    Const TABLE = "TargetTableName"

    Dim cn As Object, rs As Object
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, n As Long
    Dim col, val(5)
    col = Array("Column1", "Column2", "Column3", _
                "Column4", "Column5", "Column6")
    
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    With cn
        .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & DB
        .Open
    End With

    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.Open TABLE, cn, 2, 2, 2 'adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic, adCmdTable

    With Worksheets("To Export")
        For r = 2 To 2 ' 1 row
            For i = 0 To 5
                val(i) = .Cells(r, i + 1).Value
            Next
            ' add record
            rs.AddNew col, val
            n = n + 1
        Next
    End With
    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    MsgBox n & " records added to " & TABLE
  
End Sub
```